# How to create a single page, vertical navigation site in react like the Rolex site?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, parallax

I was wondering if someone knew how this section scrolling effect was created: [example site](https://www.rolex.com/en-us).
Libraries like FullpageJs don't fully do the trick and need a license.
I also see examples that when you even scroll a bit it scrolls/snaps directly to the next section. I want it to actually follow the user's scrolling.

Anyone any idea how you would go about to create such a scrolling effect like the site above, preferably in React or plain JS.(no jquery)?
All advice is much appreciated.